# running a function periodically in go

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a function like this:

```
func run (cmd string) [] byte {
    out,err = exec.Command(cmd).Output()
    if error!=nil { 
        log.Fatal (err) 
    }
    return out
}
```

I would like to run this command this way

```
run ("uptime") // run every 5 secs
run ("date") // run every 10 secs
```

I would like to run these commands and collect its output and do something with it. How would I do this in go?

Comment: `time.Ticker` sends notifications at regular intervals (on a channel). You could have a goroutine for each of those invocations that uses a ticker to run the command at the desired interval.

Comment: Not sure why I got a negative vote, is it such a obvious question?

Comment: You also might be interested in the cron package: https://github.com/robfig/cron

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use a [`time.Ticker`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker). There's many ways to structure the program, but you can start with a simple for loop:

```
uptimeTicker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
dateTicker := time.NewTicker(10 * time.Second)

for {
    select {
    case <-uptimeTicker.C:
        run("uptime")
    case <-dateTicker.C:
        run("date")
    }
}
```

You may then want to run the commands in a goroutine if there's a chance they could take longer than your shortest interval to avoid a backlog in the for loop. Alternatively, each goroutine could have its own for loop with a single Ticker.

Answer (score 14):

```
func main() {
    for range time.Tick(time.Second * 10) {
        function_name()
    }
}
```

This function runs every 10 sec

Comment: loved this solution for its simplicity to newbies that are starting with golang and with limited channel knowledge

Comment: This solution vs calling `time.Sleep(time.Second *10)` after calling `function_name()` is that the first call to the function happens only after 10 seconds. Using `time.Sleep` calls the function, then wait for 10 seconds before calling the function again

Comment: This seems to be more reliable than using `time.NewTicker()`. It does tick exactly at the duration you set, or I guess more like it has very small drift.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to checkout this package.
https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/cron

You can even use seconds.

```
c := cron.New(cron.WithSeconds())
c.AddFunc("*/5 * * * * *", func() { fmt.Println("Testing every 5 seconds.") })
c.Start()
```

Comment: Thanks for this example with the cron library, because Cron on Linux does not have a "seconds" interval, but this library for golang has.